# Do I need to cite the source of a famous quote in my thesis?

Tags: computer-science, quotation

I'm writing part of my Computer Science PhD and I'd like to know whether it is generally acceptable to have a reference to a famous quotation by a famous person without citing a source. For example,

> *"Program testing can be used to show the presence of bugs, but never to show their absence!"* - Edsger W. Dijkstra

Comment: The world of quoting is full of misattributing famous quotes, so I'd personally suggest it's a good practice to give a citation for those. This doesn't answer your (current) question of whether it's *generally acceptable* but generally acceptable isn't necessarily the best option.

Comment: Depends on university/department, better ask alumni or check older theses.

Comment: "Notes On Structured Programming" ([EWD249](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd02xx/EWD249.PDF)), 1970.

Answer (score 2):

But please don't decorate each chapter with a quote you took from a calendar. As JiK said, there are so many misattributions and misstatements around, you need to go to the source if you absolutely must use a quote. But as chapter decoration I find them silly. Okay, Knuth is allowed to do that, but until you reach the god-like status of Knuth, please refrain.

Comment: I think Knuth used them before having reached the god-like status. Personally, I do like *well-chosen* and *tasteful* decorations.

Comment: _Knuth is allowed to do that_ — But Knuth sources _everything_.

Comment: I meant, Knuth is allowed to use quotes for every chapter, but it looks silly if everyone does it and additionally misattributes everything. Indeed, Knuth's quotations are properly sourced.

Comment: Knuth's (co-written) 1961 paper “Algol 60 Confidential” (written while he was a PhD student at Caltech, and only his sixth publication even counting the one in MAD Magazine) has a pair of quotes at the top. So he's been doing it before reaching any particularly exalted status.