# Where to write famous quotes in my dissertation?

Tags: thesis

[sina madani](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/73447/sina-madani) asked: ["Do I need to cite the source of a famous quote in my thesis?"](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/94956/do-i-need-to-cite-the-source-of-a-famous-quote-in-my-thesis) However, my question if I choose to write famous quotes in my dissertation, where and how should I write the quotes? What should I do for both cases if I am writing them per chapter and for the whole dissertation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess if you write a quote that is representative or applies to the whole dissertation, you can have it somewhere in the beginning e.g. after the title page and before the abstract.

If now you want to add a quote that applies to a specific chapter, you can add it right below the chapter title (maybe also aligned to the right side) and before the text of the chapter begins.